# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL renamed relationship mutation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm having an issue updating a renamed relationship with a graphQL query.

Here's the related schema and Laravel models:

**Laravel Models**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Lead extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'lead_type_id',
    // ];

    protected $guarded = [];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        // 'created_at' => 'timestamp',
        // 'updated_at' => 'timestamp'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the LeadActions for the Lead.
     */
    public function leadActions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\LeadAction::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the clients for the Lead.
     */
    public function clients(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the LeadType for the Lead.
     */
    public function leadType(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\LeadType::class, 'lead_type_id');
    }
}

?>

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class LeadType extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'created_at' => 'timestamp',
        'updated_at' => 'timestamp'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the Leads for the LeadType.
     */
    public function leads(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Models\Lead::class);
    }

}
?>
```

**GraphQl Schema**

```
type Lead {
   id: ID!
   lead_type: LeadType @belongsTo(relation: "leadType")
   clients: [Client!]! @belongsToMany
   created_at: DateTime!
   updated_at: DateTime!
}
input UpdateLeadInput {
   id: ID!
   clients: UpdateClientsRelation
   lead_type: UpdateLeadTypeRelation
}
input UpdateLeadTypeRelation {
   create: CreateLeadTypeInput
   connect: ID
   update: UpdateLeadTypeInput
   upsert: UpsertLeadTypeInput
   delete: ID
   disconnect: ID
}
```

Using the following graphQl query I get an SQL error for missing column lead_type:
**Query**

```
mutation UpdateLead {
  updateLead(input: {id: 1, lead_type: {connect: 1}}) {
    id
    clients {
      id
      name
    }
    lead_type {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

**SQL Error**

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lead_type' in 'field list' (SQL: update `leads` set `lead_type` = {\"connect\":\"1\"}, `leads`.`updated_at` = 2020-01-14 17:11:17 where `id` = 1
```

I've followed the Laravel naming convention, and named the column lead_type_id on the leads table. If I remove the renaming of the lead_type relationship to leadType I can successfully run an update mutation, but I can't figure out how to get it to use the correct name for the column (lead_type_id) whilst keeping the relationship renamed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `@rename` directive? I mean you have to use it on `lead_type` in your `UpdateLeadInput`, because lighthouse looks for relation named `lead_type`, and as this is not defined, it assume that `lead_type` is an argument.

Either rename your relations in models, like:

```php
class Lead extends Model
{
    public function lead_actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\LeadAction::class);
    }

    public function lead_type(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\LeadType::class, 'lead_type_id');
    }
}
```

OR

use `@rename` directive (I didn't try it, but I mean it works like this):

```
input UpdateLeadInput {
   id: ID!
   clients: UpdateClientsRelation
   lead_type: UpdateLeadTypeRelation @rename(attribute: "leadType")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the rename directive is exactly what I was missing. I'd managed to miss this directive in the docs, and my IDE doesn't recognise it as a valid directive either.

Comment: Oh ok, `@rename` directive is [documented in API Reference](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#rename). Probably we have to mention it in some other places? You are welcome to add an issue in github repo with suggestion, where we can place it.